# Probability distribution fitting with Wasserstein metrics

Tags: probability, bayesian, modeling, model-selection, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm a physicist. I have a relatively complex physical model for a process occurring, and I can numerically solve the relevant differential equations, evaluate their solutions and produce observables, $x_i$ and $z$, let's say. The model has some parameters in it that are of interest, and correspond to my idea of physical reality, let's call them $\hat\theta$. In some sort of pseudo-maths, my physical model $f(\hat\theta)$ specifies two separate functions $g$ and $h$, $[g, h]=f(\hat\theta)$ and the functions *themselves* are physically observable: $h$ is a function of time, $z=h(t, \hat\theta)$, whereas $g$ is a discrete probability distribution function from which I obtain specific values; $g(x_i)$.

Basically, the trouble is that my observables are naturally different. $x_i$ is effectively a probability, so that the "output" is a [naturally discrete] histogram, which I can also experimentally measure; whereas $z$ is the value of something a function of time. I can also measure this data directly as a function of time.

I'd like to do a joint fit for $\hat\theta$ using, if it's computationally feasible, MCMC, or ABC if it isn't. If I were to just have the data as a function of time, I'd be quite happy to do this using a maximum likelihood approach based on minimising the $L_2$ metric between my experimental values of $h(t)$ and the model's. When it comes to fitting the *histogram*, however, I'm far less sure: whilst I could just do a least squares fit between the predicted PDF and actual bin height in a given range, this seems dependent upon, for example, bin width, or some other sort of boring hyperparameter.

An alternative approach, and one that may be more robust, would be to use an appropriate probability space metric between the two. Of these, I think that the Wasserstein metric [aka earth movers' distance] would be most appropriate for minimising between the experimental and theoretical PDFs. If we denote this metric by $W_p(\text{data}, \text{theory}(\hat\theta))$ my question is this:

**Is there any** sort of **theoretical justification for minimising**

$$
\underset{\hat{\theta}}{\mathrm{argmin}}\quad  \left|\left|h(t,\hat\theta) - z_\text{experiment} \right|\right|_{2}^{2} + W_p(x_i, g(\hat\theta)) 
$$

Alternatively, can I consider $W_p$ explicitly in some-sort of quasi-log-likelihood function, e.g. just by adding $1-W_p$ to the terms considered? What is a good framework to work in?

Finally, what sort of name is given to these types of joint estimation problems?

Comment: There are many [papers about estimation by min Wasserstein](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb95&q=estimation%20by%20minimizing%20Wasserstein%20metric&lookup=0&hl=en).  Other wise, this is for now very abstract, can you tell us some details?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Alas, the details are also more than a bit abstract ;-). Basically, I'd like to jointly fit, with one "physics model", a discrete histogram, a time-domain curve, and possibly other things that I've independently measured. There are three plausible "physics models" and I'd like to compute their AICs. I'm aware that they are derived under the conventional definition of likelihood, and I'm worried that if I just add a term based on Wasserstein, I've thrown away the interpretation of the likelihood function. Astrophysics does joint fits frequently, but not with Wasserstein.

Comment: AIC is conventionally based on maximum likelihood, so what happens if you replaces with some other estimation method I do not know, you can ask a question about that ... or you could compare the physics models based on cross validation, bootstrapping or some other simulations?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That is true. My other underlying  question might be better served as "how bad is it _really_ to do a least-squares fit with an empirical discrete PDF to a theoretical discrete PDF with mildly, but inherently, censored data" [which is why I wanted to use Wasserstein, as it is a sensible metric in probability space]

Comment: Also -- the other thing I forgot to say is that the models involve a lot of differential equations and are quite computationally expensive. Fortunately, there are all sorts of nice approximate bayesian approaches that would work quite well, certainly on the time-domain output or similar. It's just the histogram that bothers me.